# check if an ip matches any ip contained in an ip list using php

Tags: php, arrays, ip, cidr

in array $white I have an ip list like this (about 10000-12000 ips)

```
74.125.244.0/22
207.126.144.0/20
77.238.189. 
212.211.149.128/26
194.25.134.8 
194.25.134.9 
194.25.134.12       
174.2.114.12-174.2.115.255
153.2.242.243
153.2.244.12 
153.2.244.50 
153.2.244.63 
153.2.246.30 
153.2.246.31 
153.2.246.35 
153.2.247.30 
153.2.247.31 
153.2.247.32
```

So, the ip list in array $white can contain ip(s) in these three format

```
153.2.247.32 (simple ip address)
207.126.144.0/20 ( CIDR notation )
174.2.114.12-174.2.115.255 ( Hyphenated ranges )
```

My goal is to check if ips listed in another array , $ips (about 1000-2000 ips) , are present in
the $white list.

The format in the $ips list is only simple ip address like

```
207.126.144.0
207.126.141.2
201.126.144.5
```

I am doing this

```
foreach ($ips as $check) {
if (in_array($check,$white)){
echo "Ip $check exists";
}
}
```

However it's only good to check simple ip addresses , but I cannot check if the ips listed in $ips are contained in the Hyphenated ranges and CIDR ranges of $white .

I found a solution using ip_in_range.php
https://github.com/irazasyed/php-ip-range/blob/master/ip_in_range.php

```
foreach ($ips as $check) {
    if (in_array($check,$white))
    {
    echo "Ip $check exists";
    }
    else
    {
    foreach( $white as $checkrange )
    {       
if (substr_count($checkrange, '/')>=1 or substr_count($checkrange, '-')>=1 )
{ 
    if (ip_in_range($check, $checkrange)) 
{ 
    echo "Ip $check exists"; 
    break;
}
}

}
}
}
```

But it's very slow , because $white and $ips are huge lists .
Does exist a faster and more efficient solution ?

Comment: Define huge? You could fill a cache with all the ranges pre-expanded into individual IPs, then it's just a hash check and that will be O(1) to check one IP against a whitelist of any size.

Comment: About 10000 ips in $white and 1000-2000 in $ips .The ips in $ips are possible spammers and I need to check if the ips are in our $white (whitelist) before adding them in a blacklist.

Comment: is your $white list is static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre-expand all the whitelist ranges into one giant list of singular IP addresses. For example, given:

```
1.2.3.4
2.3.4.5
3.4.5.6-3.4.5.10
```

You'd process the list once to generate this list:

```
1.2.3.4
2.3.4.5
3.4.5.6
3.4.5.7
3.4.5.8
3.4.5.9
3.4.5.10
```

Then, store that list in a key/value cache. Could be something as simple as a native PHP associative array sitting in memory, or something more robust like a Redis database. Then you've got a simple equivalency check for inclusion. Implemented correctly (e.g., via `array_key_exists()` instead of `in_array()`), you'll get O(1) performance for an IP lookup, regardless of the size of the whitelist. It can't get faster.

Instead of doing all the range processing over and over again on every single IP check, you're doing it only once when the whitelist changes. You're basically giving up memory to gain CPU.

Comment: I had this idea too. However I was worried about the new array (it could be very big). However you talk about "key/value cache", I have no idea, please could you give me more details ?

Comment: I mean, any mechanism that uses a hash lookup so that you don't have to sequentially scan every item to find the one you want. E.g., if you store the array as `['1.2.3.4','2.3.4.5','3.4.5.6']` and use `in_array()` then PHP has to scan the whole array one item at a time to find the target, so the more items you have, the slower it gets. On the other hand, if you store the array as `['1.2.3.4'=>true,'2.3.4.5'=>true,'3.4.5.6'=>true]` and use `array_key_exists()` then PHP can instantly determine if the target is present, and it never gets slower, no matter how many items are in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [preg_grep](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php):

```
foreach ($ips as $check){

    if(preg_grep("/$check/i",$white))
    {
        echo $input." whitelisted";
    }else{
        echo $input." blacklisted";
    }
{
```

Comment: how can a preg_check validate a CIDR notation ? (sorry for edit it was a fault, please delete/ignore it)

Comment: I dont understand you. with code that I wrote you can check if simple IP is contained in all white listed ips (simple, CIDR, Hyphenated ranges ). But if you want also to validate CIDR notation you can use something like this https://gist.github.com/lt/4162568